# Java 8 Optional extension to carry parameters as map evolves

Tags: java, option-type

Been presented several situations where it'd have been cool to have Optional keeping references to previously mapped objects.

```java
    // Normally the following is a good candidate for Optional fluent API (imagine also all the null checks that could be necessary)

    A a = new A();
    B b = calculateB(a);
    C c = calculateC(b)
    D d = calculateD(c)
    E e = calculateE(d)

    // As 
    E e = Optional.ofNullable(a)
            .map(this::calculateB)
    ...
    
    // But the following can't be expressed with Optional API
        A a = new A();
    B b = calculateB(a);
    C c = calculateC(a, b)
    D d = calculateD(a, c)
    E e = calculateE(a, d)

    // Something like the following sounds tempting
    PowerOptional.ofNullable(a)
            .mapAndKeep(this::calculateB) // mapAndKeep would carry the input as well to next call.
            .map((a, b) -> calculateC(a, b))
            .map((a, c) -> calculateD(a, c))
            .map((a, d) -> calculateE(a, d))
            .orElse(null);
```

This could improve readability of rather cumbersome methods.
Is there a library that addresses this?
Ideas (also on naming)?

Comment: You can essentially do that by having optionals of tuples and then map from them to other tuples or entire lists of previous objects.

Comment: @zapl I thought of parameterBags but don’t feel it improves readability

Comment: You just discovered the Monad: use `flatMap` as one answer already suggests.

Answer (score 5):

It's just the `flatMap` method. It can be used for sequencing multiple operations that return `Optional`s, and it allows you to bind intermediate results to variables. In your case, it would be something like

```java
Optional.ofNullable(nullableA)
  .flatMap(a -> calculateB(a)
    .flatMap(b -> calculateC(a, b)
      .flatMap(c -> calculateD(a, c)
        .flatMap(d -> calculateE(a, d)))))
  .orElse(null)
```

Note that not only `a`, but indeed *all* intermediate results become available in the later calculation steps. In an extreme case, it could look somewhat like this:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(nullableA)
  .flatMap(a -> calculateB(a)
    .flatMap(b -> calculateC(a, b)
      .flatMap(c -> calculateD(a, b, c)
        .flatMap(d -> calculateE(a, b, c, d)))))
  .orElse(null)
```

i.e. every step could depend on the intermediate results from all previous steps.

Afaik, as of 2022, there is no special syntax for it in Java. The standard solution for avoiding the increasing indentation ([popularized in Haskell](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation)) is some kind of `do`/[`for-yield`-syntax](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/fp-functional-error-handling.html#using-a-for-expression), e.g. in Scala, that could be written vertically, and would resemble usual imperative syntax:

```scala
for
  a <- ofNullable(aNullable)
  b <- calculateB(a)
  c <- calculateC(a, b)
  d <- calculateD(a, c)
  e <- calculateE(a, d)
yield e
```